# jQuery menu bug fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been creating a multi level menu with the help of a jQuery plugin. However, I have a wierd mouse over issue.

**Issue 1**

If you mouse over "Solutions" and then move your mouse upwards off of the item and back on again it removes its class (grey background) which is fine but now your mouse is still on the menu item and the background has now gone so you have to mouse off and on again, play around and you will see. Does this make sense!?

As is always the way - I've been looking at it this for so long now that I can't see the issue and it's slowly driving me insane!

**Issue 2**

The mouseover event is attached to the `<A>` tag, which is also causing an issue, would make more sense on the `<LI>` open to tips on how to achieve this one.

---

I have created a fiddle below, please feel free to give me some insight as to how to fix this one. Thanks!

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7hced/1/

**Fiddle result:** http://jsfiddle.net/7hced/1/embedded/result/

Comment: do want to hide the menu on mouse out

Comment: Issue 1:the hover triggers the class binding and makes it toggle class="cbp-hropen". Try replace this part of js with pure css.
Issue 2:you will have to add another wrapper to your list so that your 3rd level menu will continue working correctly.

Comment: Please describe the desired behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have the following logic statement in the **open** function:

```
    if (current === idx) {
        $item.removeClass('cbp-hropen');
        current = -1;
    } else {
```

I believe this is the cause of the issues you are experiencing.
Try removing that code and see if it helps.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7hced/13/

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is that your mouse-out is not properly handled to reset the menu-item when the cursor leaves. It should reset to closed state. I suggest using jQuery's hover(over, out) method.

I checked (very) briefly, and by changing the first rule in your init() action (`$menuItems.on('mouseover', open);`) with `$menuItems.hover(open, close);` seems to fix it:

http://jsfiddle.net/7hced/3/embedded/result/

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hced/3/

Comment: Hey there - it fixes the top issue but doesn't allow you to move your mouse into the submenu?

Comment: Ah, yeah, you need to check for that too... But that should be a matter of calling the open() function for your main menu when you hover over a submenu (So when the submenu opens, it also opens it's parent).

Comment: Ceryl - Can you provide an example of how you would do this, I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: I don't have any time left, but here is some (buggy) code with par tof a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7hced/9/embedded/result/ I changed the close-action to check that the parent only closes when you hover poutside the menu. It's not fully funcitonal but it should help a little bit!

Comment: Thanks Ceryl but this works the same way as my original fiddle - has the same original issue